# Direct3D COM object call in C#

Tags: c#, com, interop, direct3d

Anyone have tried to manually call Direct3D interface from C#? I wrote the following short code and got `result == S_OK` after calling `D3D11CreateDevice()`.

I expect `GetCreationFlags()` returns `32` which is the one of arguments when I called `D3D11CreateDevice()`, but I am getting `AccessViolationException`. What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

```
[Guid("DB6F6DDB-AC77-4E88-8253-819DF9BBF140")]
interface ID3D11Device
{
    [return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetCreationFlags();
}

    [DllImport("d3d11.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private unsafe static extern int D3D11CreateDevice(
        void* arg0, int arg1, void* arg2, int arg3, void* arg4, int arg5, int arg6,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object arg7,
        void* arg8, void* arg9);

    public static void CreateDevice()
    {
        object deviceOut;
        int arg8;
        IntPtr arg9;

        unsafe
        {
            int result = D3D11CreateDevice(
                (void*)IntPtr.Zero, 1, (void*)IntPtr.Zero, 32,
                (void*)IntPtr.Zero, 0, 7,
                out deviceOut,
                &arg8,
                &arg9);
        }

        ID3D11Device dev = (ID3D11Device)deviceOut;

        uint i = dev.GetCreationFlags(); // System.AccessViolationException
    }
```

For your information, the prototypes of `D3D11CreateDevice` and `ID3D11Device::GetCreationFlags()` look like:

```
HRESULT D3D11CreateDevice(
  _In_   IDXGIAdapter *pAdapter,
  _In_   D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType,
  _In_   HMODULE Software,
  _In_   UINT Flags,
  _In_   const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevels,
  _In_   UINT FeatureLevels,
  _In_   UINT SDKVersion,
  _Out_  ID3D11Device **ppDevice,
  _Out_  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevel,
  _Out_  ID3D11DeviceContext **ppImmediateContext
);

UINT GetCreationFlags();
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you may want to consider SharpDX: http://sharpdx.org/

Comment: I know about SharpDX, but I only need a small part of D3D. SharpDX seems too big for my purpose.

Comment: Your interface declaration is not close to being correct.  It won't be small anymore after you fixed that.

Comment: maybe you can try SlimDX as well.

Comment: Someone mentioned the Windows API CodePack for examples http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: SharpDX is a direct wrapper for D3D, autogenerated, you should really take a look at this. It does not contain any logic that should make it 'big' as you stated.